# Firefox add-on SDK pattern matching not working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

When I use following code

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "http://www.page.com/user/*",
  contentScript: 'window.alert("user");'
});
```

I get alert. But I want to replace "http://www." part so I tried:

```
*://*.page.com/user/*
*://page.com/user/*
*.page.com/user/*
```

and none of those work for me. Examples from developer.mozilla.org indicate that at least one of them should work. What is wrong with those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered this problem in the past, you cannot use more than 1 `*` (wildcard) in the pattern.

You have 2 options

- Use an array of websites, i.e. `["http://www.page.com/user/*", "https://www.page.com/user/*"]`
- Use a [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) (Regular Expression)

---

Here is how you can use a RegEx to get what you wanted when you tried `*://*.page.com/user/*`

Use the following RegEx: `.+:\/\/(.+\.)?page\.com\/user\/.*`

Here is how it works (if you do not know RegEx, I would suggest learning it):

```
.+          # Any character 1+ times - Selects the Protocol (http, https, ftp)
:\/\/       # :// After Protocol (/ have to be escaped using \/)
(.+\.)?     # (Optional) Letters followed by a . (dot) - (www.)
page        # Website Name - (page)
\.com       # .com - (Top-Level Domain)
\/user\/    # Folder /user/ (/ have to be escaped using \/)
.*          # Any character 0 or more times - (Any folders / files after the /user/ folder)
```

Here is a good site to learn RegEx if you do not already know them: [RegexOne](http://regexone.com/)

So, your full `include` will be:

```
include: /.+:\/\/(.+\.)?page\.com\/user\/.*/,
```

Note than in JavaScript you define a RegEx by esclosing it in `/`s

Here is a [Live Demo](http://regexr.com/3d1uc) of the RegEx working

Comment: This is a perfect answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem! I had this problem, and I tried to figure it out for ages, until I found out you cannot use multiple wildcards. I did not realize I could use RegEx (not that I knew how to use it anyway), so I ended up with a long array to include `http`, `https`, with or without `www` for each one, and then I had to double that whole thing for `.com` and `.co.uk`!